# Suggestions for an off-line Android app to send data to server

Tags: android, offlineapps, offline-mode

how can I manage sending data (geocoordinates, speed, address, ...) to server on off-line mode in my Android application using HttpPost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [SyncAdpter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) . it automatically creates queue if internet is not available.

Create a table to store relevant information

Make connection via syncadpter to your server.

Extract the data from table and do a post

if internet available it will post the data else it will wait for internet to come.